# React/Redux: Remove from cart not working, not getting any error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm Creating a cart you can add items to, my Add_To_Cart action is working, but REMOVE_FROM_CART is not doing anything. My hunch is that the reducer is not doing the correct thing. here is my code:

Cart.js(container):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { RemoveFromCart } from '../actions/remove_from_cart';

class Cart extends Component {

  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.renderQuantity = this.renderQuantity.bind(this)
   }


  renderTotal(){
    const { cart } = this.props;
    let sum = 0;
    return (
      <div>
        ${cart.total}
      </div>
    )
  }

renderQuantity(){
    const { cart, RemoveFromCart } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(cart.quantityPerId).map(function(key){
            return <li key={key}>
          item: {key} ||
          Quantity: {cart.quantityPerId[key]} ||
          <button
            onClick={() => RemoveFromCart(key, cart.quantityPerId[key])}
            >Return
          </button></li>;
    })}
  </div>
)
}


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Cart</h3>
        Total:
          {this.renderTotal()}
        Quantity per Item:
          {this.renderQuantity()}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ RemoveFromCart }, dispatch);
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { itemList: state.itemList, cart: state.cart }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

remove_from_cart.js (Action Creator)

```
export const REMOVE_FROM_CART = 'REMOVE_FROM_CART';


export function RemoveFromCart(name, quantity) {
  return {
    type: REMOVE_FROM_CART,
    name,
    quantity
  };
}
```

reducer_cart.js (reducer)

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../actions/add_to_cart';
import { REMOVE_FROM_LIST } from '../actions/remove_from_list';


const initialState = {
  total: 0,
  quantityPerId: {}
}



const total = (state = initialState.total, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
    if (parseInt(action.quantity) > 0 ) {
        return state += parseInt(action.price)
    }
  }
}

const quantityPerId = (state = initialState.quantityPerId, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
     case ADD_TO_CART:
      if (parseInt(action.quantity) > 0) {
        return {...state, [action.name] : (state[action.name] || 0) + 1
      }

    }
case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
  Object.keys(quantityPerId).map(function(name){
    if (action.name === name && parseInt(action.quantity) > 0) {
      // return Object.assign({}, name, { name: action.quantity - 1})
      return {...state, name : state[action.name] - 1}
    }
})

  default:
    return state

  }
}

const cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      return {...state,
        total: total(state.total, action),
        quantityPerId: quantityPerId(state.quantityPerId, action)
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

 export default cart
```

Again, the problem is with REMOVE_FROM_CART.

Comment: At a quick glance, your issue is likely the use of "===" which is "strict equality" in the (action.name === name  rather then using "==" which is abstract equality.

Answer (score 1):

You nothing returning there:

```
case REMOVE_FROM_CART: {
  Object.assign()..... //but not return statement?
}
```

By redux docs each reducer needs to returning new state always. Try return your spread and see what will happens.

```
case REMOVE_FROM_CART: {
  return Object.assign... //returning spread
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import the reducer to the store, the imported code is in the `cart` function, which doesn't include the `REMOVE_FROM_CART` case...

Nobody outside this file knows about the `total` function. Therefore, when the `REMOVE_FROM_CART` action is processed, the `cart` reducer doesn't recognize it and handles it as 'default'.

Since both are handling the same state object, you need to define one function that contains both.